# undefined method `aasm_state' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I make a shopping website,I find a bug that I can't solve.I have a page to show all orders,and it can change the state of orders.When I go to that page,it will give me the following error:

> undefined method `aasm_state' for nil:NilClass

But,in rails console I can find the state of the order.Can you help me to solve this?If you want more details,please let me know.Thank you very much~

I'm so sorry that I don't have enough reputation to post images. SO I paste the code from rails console in the comment.

Comment: 2.3.1 :001 > Order.last
  Order Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" ORDER BY "orders"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Order id: 2, total: 52.8, user_id: 1, billing_name: "hgnvhmj", billing_address: "fdhgfnc", shipping_name: "fhdcnhm", shipping_address: "ghdnh", created_at: "2016-11-24 09:33:47", updated_at: "2016-11-24 09:33:48", token: "6bd6d0f2-907e-48e7-84f2-376c4127a02c", is_paid: true, payment_method: "alipay", aasm_state: "paid", is_cancel: false>

Comment: please add relevant section of the action of your controller code, route to the page you are trying to access and the view file, the line of code where this attribute `assm_state` is accessed from your `Order` object.

Comment: Can you post your orders model, or wherever you have the code for the aasm states?  Also, the view for the orders would be useful.

Comment: @RockwellRice following is the code for aasm_state include AASM
    aasm do
        state :order_placed, initial: true
        state :paid
        state :shipping
        state :shipped
        state :order_cancelled
        state :good_returned
        event :make_payment, after_commit: :pay! do
            transitions from: :order_placed, to: :paid
        end
        event :ship do
            transitions from: :paid, to: :shipping
        end
        event :delever do
            transitions from: :shipping, to: :shipped
        end
    end

Comment: @sa77This is the view file.<% case order.aasm_state %>
<% when "order_placed"%>
<%= link_to("取消订单",cancel_admin_order_path(order),method: :post) %>
<% when "paid" %>
<%= link_to("取消订单",cancel_admin_order_path(order),method: :post) %>
<%= link_to("出货",ship_admin_order_path(order),method: :post) %>
<% when "shipping" %>
<%= link_to("设为已出货",shipped_admin_order_path(order),method: :post) %>
<% when "shipped" %>
<%= link_to("退货",return_admin_order_path(order),method: :post) %>
<% when "order_cancelled" %>
订单已取消
<% when "good_returned" %>
已退货
<% end %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve this problem.It is because the view file has an issue.When you want to put it in the index.html.erb,you can't put @ before the model.